# Using math function in projections in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Node and Mongoose Trying to fetch data from a collection in which field **days** is having ***negative as well as positive numbers stored***. I want to **show all the data of days in positive** only, so therefore using **Math abs** function. but somehow it is *not working and also not showing any error*.

Code is below:

```
        let projection = {
        _id : 0,
        userId : 1,
        sum : 1,
        days : Math.abs("$days"), //This is not working
        leaveType : 1,
        reason : 1,
        fromDate : 1,
        toDate : 1,
        leaveDuration : 1,
        leaveStatus : 1,
        createdAt : 1,
        updatedAt : 1,
        rejectReason : 1,
        empName : "$userDetails.fullName",
        leaveType : "$LeaveDetails.leaveTitle",
        availableBalance : 1,
    }
```

Comment: You can use the aggregation operator  `$abs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$abs (aggregation)** is what you are looking for.
Pls check the link below:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/

```
  let projection = {
    _id : 0,
    userId : 1,
    sum : 1,
    days: {$abs: "$days" } , //This will work
    leaveType : 1,
    reason : 1,
    fromDate : 1,
    toDate : 1,
    leaveDuration : 1,
    leaveStatus : 1,
    createdAt : 1,
    updatedAt : 1,
    rejectReason : 1,
    empName : "$userDetails.fullName",
    leaveType : "$LeaveDetails.leaveTitle",
    availableBalance : 1
}
```